# Bitbucket Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've created a Bitbucket account for sharing code with friends. When I try to clone the repository, with the command

```
$ git clone https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git
```

they say :

```
$ git clone https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git
Cloning into 'wall-strass'...
fatal: https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git/info/refs not
found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I've tried to do the command "git update-server-info" but it doesn't work. I don't unterstand what to do, have you an idea please ?

[Update] Here are my commands :

```
XXXX-PC /c/repos (master)
$ export http_proxy="http://XXXXX"

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ export https_proxy="https://XXXXX"

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ cd c:/repos

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/repos/.git/

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ git remote add origin https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass
.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ echo "# This is my README" >> README.md

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ git add README.md
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ git commit -m "First commit. Adding a README."
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

XXXX /c/repos (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git/info/refs not
 found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't yet pushed anything there, there isn't anything to clone.

When you have done your first commit, push it to bitbucket, and then you should be able to clone the repository.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've tried to do this : $ echo "# This is my README" >> README.md, then $ git add README.md, then $ git commit -m "First commit. Adding a README.", then $ git push -u origin master. But at the fourth line, Git Bash doesn't answer my request (and is blocked). I use a proxy, but I've already defined http_proxy with the correct value.

Comment: Since you refer to origin, did you set up a remote? E.g. `git remote add origin https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git`

Comment: I've wrote all the commands in my first message. (and in fact, Git Bash answers the last command, but there is still a problem)

Comment: You should double-check the repository path you are using. You get exactly the error message you describe with a typo in the path, i.e. are trying to clone a non-existent repository.

Comment: I've tried to create a new project, but it still doesn't work. Is it normal that https://clubmagnan@bitbucket.org/clubmagnan/wallstrass.git displays "Oops, you've found a dead link." ?

Comment: The repository doesn't exist if you get that message. If it existed but you are not logged in, you'd get a sign-in prompt.

Comment: Did you remove the actual remote origin using `git remote rm origin` and then run `git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/project.git` again? Then `git push -u origin master` for the first push.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the HTTPS transport is somehow b0rked. Try cloning using the ssh transport:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:wallstrass/wall-strass.git
```

Comment: Then I have no idea what's going on in your environment.

Answer (score -1):

put this https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git instead of

$ git clone https://wallstrass@bitbucket.org/wallstrass/wall-strass.git

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @okiharaherbst: There are no links given. Please review carefully.

Comment: @cfi You are wrong. Two links are given. If the intention was to suggest one link instead of the other, then replier should learn the basics of formatting on SO. Please read answers carefully next time.

Comment: @okiharaherbst: Please read the question, and compare the "links" given to the question. You will see that this is about accessing a certain git repository. And online git repos are addressed via urls. So the urls in this answer are not links in the sense of pointing SO users to outside resources.